# Pascal pointers not behaving as expected

Tags: pointers, pascal

For [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com) I'm building a referee for a card game called War. Rules described [here](https://www.xarg.org/puzzle/codingame/war/)). TL;DR: the persons with the highest drawn card adds both cards to the bottom of his/her card stack.
I've build a linked-list in Pascal to hold the card stacks. But pascal pointers are not behaving as I expect:

For example, I give the program the following input (slightly modified):

```
9
8C
KD
AH
QH
3D
KD
AH
QH
6D
9
8D
2D
3H
4D
4S
2D
3H
4D
7H
```

The example output is:

```
nrCards: 5
Player1: 13 14 12 6
Player2: 2 3 4 7
Player1: 14 12 6
Player2: 3 4 7
Player1: 12 6
Player2: 4 7
Player1: 6
Player2: 7
Player1:
Player2: 6 7
2 5
```

I.e., the nextNode pointer of the last element is mostly not updated properly...

Code:

```pascal
program Answer;
{$H+}
uses sysutils, math, strutils;

type
    TNode = record
        val : Int32;
        nextNode : ^TNode;
    end;
    TNodePtr = ^TNode;
    TNodePtrPtr = ^TNodePtr;
var
    size1 : Int32;
    size2 : Int32;
    cards : Array of TNode;
    player1first : TNodePtr = nil;
    player1last : TNodePtr = nil;
    player2first : TNodePtr = nil;
    player2last : TNodePtr = nil;
    winnerLast : TNodePtrPtr = nil;
    i : Int32;
    Line: String;
    turns : Int32 = 0;
    nrCards : Int32 = 1;
    cardIt : TNodePtr = nil;

    function ParseIn(i : Int32) : String;
    begin
        ParseIn := ExtractWord(i, Line, [' ']);
    end;

    function War(pl1it, pl2it : TNodePtr) : Int32;
    var
        nrCards : Int32 = 5;
        i :Int32; // not reuse?
    begin
        for i := 0 to 3 do begin
            pl1it := pl1it^.nextNode;
            pl2it := pl2it^.nextNode;
            if (pl1it = nil) or (pl2it = nil) then
                exit(0);
        end;
        while (pl1it^.val = pl2it^.val) do begin
            nrCards := nrCards + 4;
            for i := 0 to 3 do begin
                pl1it := pl1it^.nextNode;
                pl2it := pl2it^.nextNode;
                if (pl1it = nil) or (pl2it = nil) then
                    exit(0);
            end;
        end;
        if pl1it^.val > pl2it^.val then
            // player 1 wins
            War := nrCards
        else
            // player 2 wins
            War := -nrCards;
    end;
begin
    readln(Line);
    size1 := StrToInt(ParseIn(1));
    Setlength(cards, size1);
    for i := 0 to size1-1 do begin
        readln(Line);
        //writeln(StdErr, Line);
        case Line[1] of
            '1' : cards[i].val := 10;
            'J' : cards[i].val := 11;
            'Q' : cards[i].val := 12;
            'K' : cards[i].val := 13;
            'A' : cards[i].val := 14;
            else cards[i].val := Integer(Line[1])-48;
        end;
        if i = size1-1 then
            cards[i].nextNode := nil
        else
            cards[i].nextNode := @cards[i+1];
    end;

    readln(Line);
    size2 := StrToInt(ParseIn(1));
    Setlength(cards, size1+size2);
    for i := size1 to size1+size2-1 do begin
        readln(Line);
        //writeln(StdErr, Line);
        case Line[1] of
            '1' : cards[i].val := 10;
            'J' : cards[i].val := 11;
            'Q' : cards[i].val := 12;
            'K' : cards[i].val := 13;
            'A' : cards[i].val := 14;
            else cards[i].val := Integer(Line[1])-48;
        end;
        if i = size1+size2-1 then
            cards[i].nextNode := nil
        else
            cards[i].nextNode := @cards[i+1];
    end;

    player1first := @cards[0];
    player1last := @cards[size1-1];
    player2first := @cards[size1];
    player2last := @cards[size1+size2-1];

    // now for the game
    while (player1first <> nil) and (player2first <> nil) do begin
        if player1first^.val <> player2first^.val then begin
            if player1first^.val > player2first^.val then begin
                // player 1 wins
                writeln(StdErr, 'Player1 wins');
                winnerLast := @player1last;
            end else begin
                // player 2 wins
                writeln(StdErr, 'Player2 wins');
                winnerLast := @player2last;
            end;
            winnerLast^^.nextNode := player1first;
            winnerLast^ := player1first;
            player1first := player1first^.nextNode;
            winnerLast^^.nextNode := player2first;
            winnerLast^ := player2first;
            player2first := player2first^.nextNode;
            winnerLast^^.nextNode := nil;
        end else begin
            // war
            nrCards := War(player1first, player2first);
            writeln(StdErr, 'nrCards: ', nrCards);
            if nrCards = 0 then
                break;
            if nrCards > 0 then begin
                writeln(StdErr, 'Player1 wins');
                winnerLast := @player1last;
            end else begin
                writeln(StdErr, 'Player2 wins');
                winnerLast := @player2last;
                nrCards := -nrCards;
            end;
            for i := 0 to nrCards-1 do begin
                winnerLast^^.nextNode := player1first;
                winnerLast^ := player1first;
                player1first := player1first^.nextNode;
            end;
            for i := 0 to nrCards-1 do begin
                winnerLast^^.nextNode := player2first;
                winnerLast^ := player2first;
                player2first := player2first^.nextNode;
            end;
            winnerLast^^.nextNode := nil;
        end;
        turns := turns + 1;
        write(StdErr, 'Player1: ');
        cardIt := player1first;
        while cardIt <> nil do begin
            write(StdErr, cardIt^.val, ' ');
            cardIt := cardIt^.nextNode;
        end;
        writeln(StdErr, ' ');
        write(StdErr, 'Player2: ');
        cardIt := player2first;
        while cardIt <> nil do begin
            write(StdErr, cardIt^.val, ' ');
            cardIt := cardIt^.nextNode;
        end;
        writeln(StdErr, ' ');
    end;

    // end game
    if nrCards = 0 then
        // equal
        writeln('PAT')
    else if player2first = nil then
        // player 2 won
        writeln('1 ',turns)
    else 
        // player 2 won
        writeln('2 ',turns);

    flush(StdErr); flush(output); // DO NOT REMOVE
end.
```

I have a background in C/C++/C#, which could explain my coding style. The same program in C works correctly. IMHO I've *literally* translated it...

C code:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TNode {
    int val;
    struct TNode* nextNode;
};

int War(struct TNode* pl1It, struct TNode* pl2It) {
    int nrCards = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        pl1It = pl1It->nextNode;
        pl2It = pl2It->nextNode;
        if (pl1It == NULL || pl2It == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (pl1It->val == pl2It->val) {
        nrCards += 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            pl1It = pl1It->nextNode;
            pl2It = pl2It->nextNode;
            if (pl1It == NULL || pl2It == NULL) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (pl1It->val > pl2It->val) {
        // player 1 wins
        return nrCards;
    } else {
        // player 2 wins
        return -nrCards;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct TNode cards[52];

    int size1;
    scanf("%d", &size1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
        char Line[4];
        scanf("%s", Line);
             if (Line[0] == '1') cards[i].val = 10;
        else if (Line[0] == 'J') cards[i].val = 11;
        else if (Line[0] == 'Q') cards[i].val = 12;
        else if (Line[0] == 'K') cards[i].val = 13;
        else if (Line[0] == 'A') cards[i].val = 14;
        else cards[i].val = (int)Line[0] - 48;

        if (i == size1 - 1) cards[i].nextNode = NULL;
        else cards[i].nextNode = &cards[i + 1];
    }

    int size2;
    scanf("%d", &size2);
    for (int i = size1; i < size1 + size2; ++i) {
        char Line[4];
        scanf("%s", Line);
             if (Line[0] == '1') cards[i].val = 10;
        else if (Line[0] == 'J') cards[i].val = 11;
        else if (Line[0] == 'Q') cards[i].val = 12;
        else if (Line[0] == 'K') cards[i].val = 13;
        else if (Line[0] == 'A') cards[i].val = 14;
        else cards[i].val = (int)Line[0] - 48;

        if (i == size1 + size2 - 1) cards[i].nextNode = NULL;
        else cards[i].nextNode = &cards[i + 1];
    }

    struct TNode* player1first = &cards[0];
    struct TNode* player1last = &cards[size1 - 1];
    struct TNode* player2first = &cards[size1];
    struct TNode* player2last = &cards[size1 + size2 - 1];

    int nrOfCards = 1; // has to do with check
    int turns = 0;
    // now for the game
    while (player1first != NULL && player2first != NULL) {
        if (player1first->val != player2first->val) {
            struct TNode** winnerLast = NULL;
            if (player1first->val > player2first->val) {
                // player 1 wins
                fprintf(stderr, "Player 1 wins.\n");
                winnerLast = &player1last;
            } else {
                // player 2 wins
                fprintf(stderr, "Player 2 wins.\n");
                winnerLast = &player2last;
            }
            (*winnerLast)->nextNode = player1first;
            (*winnerLast) = player1first;
            player1first = player1first->nextNode;
            (*winnerLast)->nextNode = player2first;
            (*winnerLast) = player2first;
            player2first = player2first->nextNode;
            (*winnerLast)->nextNode = NULL;
        } else {

            // war
            fprintf(stderr, "War: ");
            nrOfCards = War(player1first, player2first);
            if (nrOfCards == 0) break;
            struct TNode** winnerLast;
            if (nrOfCards > 0) {
                // Player 1 wins
                fprintf(stderr, "Player 1 wins.\n");
                winnerLast = &player1last;
            } else {
                // Player 2 wins
                fprintf(stderr, "Player 2 wins.\n");
                nrOfCards = -nrOfCards;
                winnerLast = &player2last;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCards; ++i) {
                (*winnerLast)->nextNode = player1first;
                (*winnerLast) = player1first;
                player1first = player1first->nextNode;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCards; ++i) {
                (*winnerLast)->nextNode = player2first;
                (*winnerLast) = player2first;
                player2first = player2first->nextNode;
            }
            (*winnerLast)->nextNode = NULL;
        }
        turns = turns + 1;
    }

    // end game
    if (nrOfCards == 0) {
        // equal
        printf("PAT\n");
    } else if (player2first == NULL) {
        // player 2 won
        printf("1 %d\n", turns);
    } else {
        // player 2 won
        printf("2 %d\n", turns);
    }
    // Write an action using printf(). DON'T FORGET THE TRAILING \n
    // To debug: fprintf(stderr, "Debug messages...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain why pascal pointers are behaving so differently, or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pascal pointers are behaving properly, I'm sure. The main problem is probably your implementation of a linked list. I didn't read your code, but it is easy to get things wrong there. Assuming there are not too many cards and players, why are you using a linked list at all? In FreePascal or Delphi you could use TList or TObjectList much more easily. Just like in C++, you would use something like a vector<>.

Comment: FWIW, your translation is not really literal. Take the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)`. This translates into `for i := 0 to 3 do`, **not** `for i := 0 to 4 do`. In C, the `i`index is always `< 4`, so it must be in Pascal too. This could be one of the problems with your code. But you could do some debugging to find out your errors. The debugger is quite good.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks for finding that bug. That fixes part of my problem. However, it still seems that the player1last^.nextNode is not update properly. player2last^.nextnode is correctly updated it seems!

Comment: There is only one proper way to find out: debug. Either add a lot of Writelns (temporarily, of course) that show what happens, or log this some other way. Or single step with a debugger and watch the variables. Should be doable, with the few lines of input you have. FWIW, if you are using FreePascal, you can use something like `Format('%p', [myPointer]);` to show the value of pointers, or the debugger. In Delphi, I would use the IDE debugger. It is very good.

Comment: FWIW, is the ghost of Dijkstra still present, in the TU Eindhoven? (I was born in Eindhoven).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I don't really know what you're referring to. Never heard the term in my 10 years in Eindhoven... But anyhow, I think I found my answer. I will look into the delphi ide.

Comment: Ok, ghost is probably the wrong word. I meant "geest", i.e. spirit. He was quite famous and quite outspoken, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, which I do not fully understand yet.

The problem is caused by de use of dynamic array `cards`. That's also the big difference between the C code and the pascal code. I'm was doing

```
readln(Line);
size1 := StrToInt(ParseIn(1));
Setlength(cards, size1);
for i := 0 to size1-1 do begin
    readln(Line);
    [...]
end;

readln(Line);
size2 := StrToInt(ParseIn(1));
Setlength(cards, size1+size2);
for i := size1 to size1+size2-1 do begin
```

That second Setlength seems to have invalidated the last element of my initial array.. It seems `player1last^.nextNode` and `cards[size-1].nextNode` were no longer connected. I don't exactly understand what happened underwater... I can only guess that Setlength reallocates the memory and copies the contents **thereby invalidating all existing pointers**! If this is the case, this was not properly explained in the tutorials I found.

I could luckily fix this as there are a maximum of 52 cards, so by choosing a fixed-length array I could fix this.

```
cards : Array[0..51] of TNode;
```

### EDIT:

OK I found a source giving me the answer [Dynamic array - Free Pascal wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array)

> Although writing to elements of dynamic arrays does not create a new instance of the array (no copy-on-write as it exists for Ansistrings) using SetLength on such arrays does create a copy! So if 2 dynamic array variables point to the same array (one has been assigned to the other) they do not do so after using SetLength on one (or both) of them. After the SetLength() call the two variables are distinct arrays whose elements are independent from each other.

Comment: This is halfway obvious, since arrays always are continuous memory streams (not fragmented) - to extend an array means to occupy the new requested length in memory (which is often elsewhere). Likewise shortening the length will most likely never re-create the array.